# CORS issue browsing Mac localhost app that uses Auth0 from IE11 in Parallels

Tags: angularjs, macos, oauth, cors, internet-explorer-11

We've got an Angular app that uses Auth0 for SSO login. We primarily use Macs and develop and test locally using the localhost web server. Browsing the site locally using browsers on Mac works fine. We can authenticate and the subsequent redirect does the right thing. The problem is browsing with IE. We can connect to the localhost web server on OS X using the IP address. We had to edit the Windows hosts file to map the Mac's IP address to localhost due to our app using full URLs/URIs as primary keys, so that the keys match.

When I browse the site using IE11 on Parallels, login using Auth0, it looks to authenticate just fine, but afterwards, we get an error when it tries to redirect:

XMLHttpRequest for https://mindjet.auth0.com/tokeninfo? required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).

Auth0 does have a field for specifying allowed CORS origins, and I tried every conceivable URL that our app exposes, even just *. But nothing worked. In our Angular app, I've tried setting $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true; That didn't work either. I'm new to the CORS concept, so any insights would be greatly appreciated. We just want to find a way to test with IE without having to deploy to a dev server.

Answer (score 1):

Our main issue that we couldn't test with IE11 seems to have been resolved by updating our auth0-angular and auth0-widget libraries to the latest version. I still occasionally see warnings about CORS issues in the console, but we are able to login and get redirected to the correct part of our app.